# Javascript / jQuery - Mega menu style menu - having issues with mouseenter / mouse leave

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am having issues with this Javascript menu. Basically I am trying to change the mega menu dropdown on elements that have a certain class. I am editing a wordpress theme's menu, so this is kind of a hack to add extra functionality to the menu. Basically I am getting multiple mouse enter events happening and just can't get it work properly. Sometimes it won't remove the visible class. sometimes it will jump up and down. I just need some help cleaning it up. I am getting a bit stuck. Really appreciate the help guys.

```js
// Mega Menu 
jQuery(function($) {

  $('[data-js=js-navigation-main]').on({

    mouseenter: function() {

      var mega_element = 'header nav ul li';
      var mega_menu_class = mega_element + '.mega_menu';
      var mega_ids = [];

      $(mega_menu_class).each(function(i) {
        mega_ids[i] = $(this).attr('id');
      });

      $(mega_element).on({

        mouseenter: function() {
          var this_id = $(this).attr('id');
          console.log('LEAVE ID');
          console.log(this_id);

          if ($.inArray(this_id, mega_ids) != -1) {

            var hover_array_key = $.inArray(this_id, mega_ids);
            var mega_menu_id_val = mega_ids[hover_array_key];

            // console.log(mega_menu_id_val);

            toggleMegaMenuList(mega_menu_id_val);
          } else {
            checkHoverElement();
          }
        },
        mouseout: function(e) {

          var this_id = $(this).attr('id');
          console.log('LEAVE ID');
          console.log(this_id);

          if ($.inArray(this_id, mega_ids) != -1) {

            var hover_array_key = $.inArray(this_id, mega_ids);
            var mega_menu_id_val = mega_ids[hover_array_key];

            toggleMegaMenuList(mega_menu_id_val);

          } else {
            checkHoverElement();
          }
        }

      });

    },
    mouseleave: function(e) {

      checkHoverElement();

    }

  });

});

function checkHoverElement() {

  jQuery('[data-js=mega_menu_list]').each(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).is(':visible')) {
      jQuery(this).closest('[data-js=mega_menu_drop_down]').slideUp();
    }
    jQuery(this).removeClass('visible');
  });

}

function toggleMegaMenuList(mega_id) {

  var temp_list_id;

  jQuery('[data-js=mega_menu_list]').each(function() {

    temp_list_id = 'menu-item-' + jQuery(this).data('menu-id');

    if (temp_list_id == mega_id) {

      if (jQuery(this).hasClass('visible')) {
        jQuery(this).closest('[data-js=mega_menu_drop_down]').stop().slideUp();
        jQuery(this).removeClass('visible');
      } else {
        jQuery(this).closest('[data-js=mega_menu_drop_down]').stop().slideDown();
        jQuery(this).addClass('visible');
      }

    }

  });
}
```

```css
 nav {

   margin-top: 20px;

   position: relative;

   ul {

     -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;

     display: -webkit-box;

     display: flex;

     width: 100%;

     justify-content: space-around;

     align-items: flex-start;

     align-content: flex-start;

     margin-left: auto!important;

     float: none;

     margin-right: auto!important;

     li {

       display: block;

       text-align: center;

       a {

         color: #ffffff!important;

         opacity: 0.75!important;

         transition: opacity 0.2s linear, color 0.2s linear;

         padding: 20px 10px!important;

         opacity: 1 !important;

         margin-bottom: -1px;

         color: #fff;

         font-family: Raleway;

         text-transform: uppercase;

         font-size: 20px;

         display: block;

         line-height: 28px;

         font-weight: 800;

         &: hover {

           color: $prim_color;

           background: #6A7B52;

         }

         @media (max-width: $grid_m) {

           font-size: 16px;

         }

       }

       ul {

         display: block;

         background: #6A7B52;

         width: 100%;

         li {

           width: 100%;

           a {

             background: none;

           }

         }

       }

     }

   }

 }

 .mega_menu_drop_down {

   width: 100%;

   height: 300px;

   background: #6A7B52;

   color: #fff;

   top: 150px;

   display: none;

   padding: 20px;

   @include box-sizing();

   &.visible {

     display: block;

   }

   .mega_menu_list {

     display: none;

     color: #fff;

     &.visible {

       display: block;

     }

     h2,

     h3 {

       color: #fff;

     }

   }

 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav data-js="js-navigation-main">

  <ul class="sf-menu container row sf-js-enabled sf-arrows" style="visibility: visible;">
    <li id="menu-item-13" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item menu-item-13"><a href="http://localhost/bcoc/" style="padding-bottom: 47px; padding-top: 19px;">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-49" class="mega_menu menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpbdp_category menu-item-49"><a href="http://localhost/bcoc/business-directory/wpbdp_category/accommodation/" style="padding-bottom: 47px; padding-top: 19px;">Accommodation</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-50" class="mega_menu menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpbdp_category menu-item-50"><a href="http://localhost/bcoc/business-directory/wpbdp_category/businesses/" style="padding-bottom: 47px; padding-top: 19px;">Businesses</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-29"><a href="http://localhost/bcoc/events/" style="padding-bottom: 47px; padding-top: 19px;">Events</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-28"><a href="http://localhost/bcoc/activities/" style="padding-bottom: 47px; padding-top: 19px;">Activities</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-51" class="mega_menu menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpbdp_category menu-item-51"><a href="http://localhost/bcoc/business-directory/wpbdp_category/community-groups/" style="padding-bottom: 47px; padding-top: 19px;">Community Groups</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-26"><a href="http://localhost/bcoc/about/" style="padding-bottom: 47px; padding-top: 19px;">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="mega_menu_drop_down" data-js="mega_menu_drop_down">

    <div class="container">

      <div data-js="mega_menu_list" class="mega_menu_list" data-menu-id="49">
        <h3>Menu 1</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">test</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">test2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">fgdgdf</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">dfg</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">dsfdsfsf</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div data-js="mega_menu_list" class="mega_menu_list" data-menu-id="50">
        <h3>Menu 2</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">test</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">test2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">fgdgdf</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">dfg</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">dsfdsfsf</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div data-js="mega_menu_list" class="mega_menu_list" data-menu-id="51">
        <h3>Menu 3</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">test</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">test2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">fgdgdf</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">dfg</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">dsfdsfsf</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>

</nav>
```